# How to do an inductive proof

Tags: coq, proof, induction

I have to show that :

```
Lemma bsuccOK: forall l, value (bsucc l) = S (value l).
```

with an induction proof, but I don't understand how to do it.

Here is the bsucc function:

```
Fixpoint bsucc (l: list bool): list bool := match l with
|[]=>[]
|r::true=>(bsucc r)::false
|r::false=>r::true
end.

Lemma bsucc_test1: bsucc [false;true;false;true] = [true;true;false;true].

Proof.
easy.
Admitted.
```

It gives the successor of a list of booleans representing a binary number.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which binary representation do you use ?
If you consider Least significant bits first, then for instance `4` is represented as `[false;false;true]`.

Here is a definition of `bsucc`and `value`. Note the order of arguments in list notations, and a slight change in `bsucc []`.   Hope it's OK.

```
Require Import List Lia.
Import ListNotations. 

(** Least significant bit first  *)

Fixpoint bsucc (l: list bool):  list bool :=
  match l with
  | []  =>[true]
  | true::r => false:: (bsucc r)
  | false::r => true::r
  end.

Fixpoint value (s:list bool):  nat:=
  match s with
  | []   => 0
  | true::r => S (2 * value r)
  | false::r => 2 * value r
  end.

Compute value [false;false;true]. (* 4 *)
```

Then, your goal is solvable, by induction on `l`.  Tactics you may also use are `cbn`or `simpl`, `case`, `rewrite`, and `lia`(for linear arithmetic).

Comment: I have been trying what you have advised me : Lemma bsuccOK: forall l, value (bsucc l) = S (value l).
Proof.
induction l.
{simpl.
reflexivity. }
simpl.
rewrite <- IHl. but here I get an error : "Found no subterm matching "S (value l)" in the current goal." Why can't I use IHl?

Comment: Well, when you have a goal `value (bsucc (a :: l)) = S (value (a :: l))`.  If you call `simpl`, you get a term with two `if a then ...`.   You may type `case a` or `destruct a`, then `simpl`. The two new sub-goals obtained by this case analysis are easy to solve (with rewritings, simplification, automatic arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you, here the answer I finally found:

```
Lemma bsuccOK: forall l, value (bsucc l) = S (value l).
Proof.
induction l; auto.
destruct a.
-simpl.
rewrite IHl.
lia.
-simpl.
lia.
Qed.
```